# Set value to parameter during UPDATE query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In MySQLThere is a table include ID, DAT, AMN, FLWC, FLWD, TYP. I would like to sort table by DAT and ID (DAT is first keyword in sort) then update FLWC and FLWD from previous record depend on TYP. for example if 0:previous record and 1:current record then:

```
if typ1==d then (flwc1=flwc0 AND flwd1=flwd0+amn1)
if typ1==c then (flwc1=flwc0+amn AND flwd1=flwd0)
```

You can see that flwc and flwd will be set to next record and one of them will be sum to AMN depend on TYP value.

Table before changes:

```
-- id__dat__amn__flwc__flwd__typ
-- 1   10   100  0     0     d
-- 2   11   200  0     0     c
-- 3   12   300  0     0     d
-- 4   13   400  0     0     c
-- 5   14   500  0     0     d
-- 6   15   600  0     0     c
-- 7   16   700  0     0     d
```

Table after UPDATE:

```
-- id__dat__amn__flwc__flwd__typ
-- 1   10   100  0     100   d
-- 2   11   200  200   100   c
-- 3   12   300  200   400   d
-- 4   13   400  600   400   c
-- 5   14   500  600   900   d
-- 6   15   600  1200  900   c
-- 7   16   700  1200  1600  d
```

I did it in MS SQL server but MySQL seems is poor in such case (**set value to parameter during update query**), solution in MS SQL Server:

```
declare @sumc decimal
declare @sumd decimal
set @sumc=0
set @sumd=0

update myTable set 
    @sumc+= case typ when 'c' then amn else 0 end, flwc=@sumc,
    @sumd+= case typ when 'd' then amn else 0 end, flwd=@sumd
```

I need the above query in MySQL. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with MySQL.

An example that could be useful.

table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Incrementar` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);
```

Inserting test records:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`Incrementar`) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO `test` (`Incrementar`) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO `test` (`Incrementar`) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO `test` (`Incrementar`) VALUES (0);
```

UPDATE:

```
SET @tempVariable = 1;

UPDATE test SET Incrementar = (@tempVariable:=@tempVariable+1)
```

Result:

```
Id  Incrementar
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

Comment: So I need at least one temp field (Incrementar) ?

Comment: You look at my other answer.

Comment: But this answer is better and I did my job by it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My previous response was an example. What you need is:

```
SET @sumc=0; 
SET @sumd=0;

UPDATE myTable SET 
 flwc= (SELECT @sumc := IF(typ = 'c', amn + @sumc, @sumc)),
 flwd= (SELECT @sumd := IF(typ = 'd', amn + @sumd, @sumd));
```